# Compare two double value for equality without calculations involved

Tags: java

I know that isn't save to directly compare two double values after some calculations are involved.
But can I compare **safely for equality** a value initialized from a literal with the same literal used for initialization?

For example:

```
Double[] dValues = [...];
double minValue = Double.MAX_VALUE;
for(Double d:dValues) {
  if(d!=null)
    minValue = Math.min(d,minValue)
}

//Is that safe?
boolean someValueFound = minValue!=Double.MAX_VALUE
```

Comment: Note that there is also a preexisting [min method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#min(java.util.Collection)) for collections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, in this case it will be safe.

It will be always safe as long as you will be not performing any computations/casting/etc. on the affected value - which would might cause some roundings.

This is also safe, because the comparison happens on native/simple types, the outcome would be different if you would use Double instead of double.

Answer (score 0):

Its save. the only problem with `Float` and `Double` is the rounding while computing operations.

If you ever want to compare such computated values allow a little delta difference.